# Problema con llamada a función de ajax con javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, vb.net

Resulta que estoy haciendo una función con ajax para poder llamar a un procedimiento de vb, la función es la siguiente:

```
function ValidarEmailSI() {
if ((document.getElementById("txtMail").value == document.getElementById("txtConfirmMail").value) && document.getElementById("txtConfirmMail").value != "") {
    var pageURL = '<%=ResolveUrl("ValidateEmail.aspx")%>'
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: pageURL + '/verificaremail',
        data: '{email: "' + $("#<%=txtConfirmMail.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.d == 'False') {
                alert('Correo invalido');
                document.getElementById("txtConfirmMail").select();
                document.getElementById("txtConfirmMail").focus();

                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

}

**Todo funciona bien si** mando a llamar a la función con un evento onblur, es decir hace el llamado al procedimiento: ValidateEmail.aspx/verificaremail :

```
<input name="txtConfirmMail" type="text" class="formsbord" id="txtConfirmMail" onblur="javascript:(ValidarEmailSI());" onpaste="return false" runat="server" maxlength = "50" tabindex="9" style="width: 170px"></td>
```

El problema está cuando intento incorporar esa funcion dentro de otra función:

```
function ValidarCampos(){

 if (ValidarEmailSI()) {
     validacionemail = true;
 }
 else {
     validacionemail = false; 
 }
 //Aquí podría pasar al siguiente paso si validacionemail me dio true
}
```

El problema es que si lo hago así, ajax nunca entra al procedimiento ValidateEmail.aspx/verificaremail, por lo tanto siempre me da false.

¿Está mal al momento en el que hago el llamado de la función ValidarEmailSI() y almacenar el resultado?.

Agradezco el apoyo.

Comment: No puedes hacer un return dentro de un ajax! La función ajax se ejecuta de forma independiente del resto del código, lo que significa que cuando se ejecuta un ajax, no se espera respuesta y sigue ejecutándose el resto del código

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, me ayudó muchísimo, solo tengo una pregunta, ni por callback es posible devolverle un valor? O poniendo el parámetro de Async: false?

Comment: Tengo entendido que puedes mediante una función, y no, ya intenté Async: false, jaja, te dejo un enlace (inglés) donde explican esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success